# SQL Running total grouped by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using this Query, I need to populate the `NULL` column with running total for each row where it would correspond to the paid amount over the period of a calendar year, year to date, of the current table. This running total should be grouped by `member_id`.

```
SELECT id=identity(int,1,1), cast(null as numeric(22,3)) as max_running_total, *
INTO #temp
FROM Customer_DB..Sales_Table
ORDER BY Date_Column asc

UPDATE #temp
SET max_running_total = (SELECT SUM(paid_amount)
                         FROM #temp
                         WHERE id <= id
                         GROUP BY member_id)
```

Comment: Where's your table structure?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? 2012+, or 2008R2 (or prior)?

Comment: sorry about that. SQL server 2008. The table i'm selevting from is about 200,000 rows of transaction data, such as paid_amount, sales tax, date, member_id, member name, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given the schema, I have taken a sample schema and have tried to a rolling sum. You can use the same sql windows functions and achieve your results

```
CREATE TABLE amt 
  ( 
     id            INT, 
     paid_amount   DECIMAL, 
     running_total DECIMAL 
  ) 

insert INTO amt VALUES (1, 100, NULL), (2, 50, NULL), (3, 50, NULL) 

SELECT id, paid_amount, 
 SUM(paid_amount) over(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_total 
FROM amt
```

Comment: Window functions only work on SQL Sever 2012 and later.

Comment: is this function available for 2008? It also doesn't take into account the member_id. I need the running total to be for each member, where it shows how much that member has paid, YTD.